# Finding a pre-visible process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

**Question**: Let $W_t$ be a standard brownian motion under **P** with filtration $\mathscr F_t$. Let:
$$
M_t=\mathbb E[W_T^2|\mathscr F_t]
$$
Show that $M$ is a **P** martingale.

This is simple enough using Tower's law, however, the second part of the question asks:

What is the martingale representation for M. That is, find the previsible process $\phi_t$ with:
$$
dM_t=\phi_tdW_t
$$
I know that by the martingale representation theorem, the process exists, but how do I go about actually finding it?

Comment: Hint: Write $M_t$ as a deterministic function of $(W_t,t)$ and use Itô's formula.

Comment: Hint 2: $W_T = W_T - W_t + W_t$.

Comment: OP: Any luck with this pair of hints?

Comment: yes, I eventually got that $\phi_t=2W_t$. Thanks both for your help.

Comment: @dimebucker91 Maybe you could write an answer. In this way, this could help future users.